# When a touch the screen my random AVFoundation sound make it slightly glitch

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit, avfoundation

I have a game that is constantly flowing and in order for the game to be played properly there needs to be zero glitches or stutter in the frame rate. I have a sound that is pulled from a random select as shown below there all named Jump (Jump is the 2sec sound) but when it does pull it from the random picker everything on the screen stops for a slight moment then goes back to what it supposed to be. and when a take the calling of the function out "Jump()" The game works fine with No stutters but of course No sound either. does anybody know why? the sound its self is fine but everything around it like an animation stutters Is there a better way to import sound in SpriteKit?

Code:

```
      class SecondScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var JumpURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:    NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType:   "mp3")!)
     var Jump = AVAudioPlayer()
      var Jump1URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
       var Jump1 = AVAudioPlayer()
     var Jump2URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:   NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
     var Jump2 = AVAudioPlayer()
     var Jump3URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump3 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Jump4URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump4 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Jump5URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump5 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Jump6URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump6 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Jump7URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump7 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Jump8URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump8 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Jump9URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump9 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Jump10URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump10 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Jump11URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump11 = AVAudioPlayer()
var Jump12URL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JustThePopinCutOffJump", ofType: "mp3")!)
var Jump12 = AVAudioPlayer()


   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

     Jump = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump.volume = 0.10
    Jump1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump1.volume = 0.10
    Jump2 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump2.volume = 0.10
    Jump3 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump3.volume = 0.10
    Jump4 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump4.volume = 0.10
    Jump5 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump5.volume = 0.10
    Jump6 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump6.volume = 0.10
    Jump7 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump7.volume = 0.10
    Jump8 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump8.volume = 0.10
    Jump9 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump9.volume = 0.10
    Jump10 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump10.volume = 0.10
    Jump11 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump11.volume = 0.10
    Jump12 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: JumpURL, error: nil)
    Jump12.volume = 0.10

      func PlayCheeringEffect() {

CheeringEffect.play()

}

func PlayJumpEffect() {

Jump.play()

}
func PlayJump1Effect() {

    Jump1.play()

}
func PlayJump2Effect() {

    Jump2.play()

}
func PlayJump3Effect() {

    Jump3.play()

}
func PlayJump4Effect() {

    Jump4.play()

}
func PlayJump5Effect() {

    Jump5.play()

}

func PlayJump6Effect() {

    Jump6.play()

}
func PlayJump7Effect() {

    Jump7.play()

}
func PlayJump8Effect() {

    Jump8.play()

}
func PlayJump9Effect() {

    Jump9.play()

}
func PlayJump10Effect() {

    Jump10.play()

}
func PlayJump11Effect() {

    Jump11.play()

}
func PlayJump12Effect() {

    Jump12.play()

}



  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


    func randomjump() {
    let randompick = rand() % 12;
    switch (randompick) {
    case 0:
        Jump.play()
        break;
    case 1:
        Jump1.play()
        break;
    case 2:
        Jump2.play()
        break;
    case 3:
        Jump3.play()
        break;
    case 4:
        Jump4.play()
        break;
    case 5:
        Jump5.play()
        break;
    case 6:
        Jump6.play()
        break;
    case 7:
        Jump7.play()
        break;
    case 8:
        Jump8.play()
        break;
     case 9:
        Jump9.play()
        break;
     case 10:
        Jump10.play()
        break;
     case 11:
        Jump11.play()
        break;
    default: Jump12.play()
        break;
      }
     }

    randomjump()
```

Comment: Are you running your app in the simulator? If it is running in the simulator performance will not be as good as on a real device.

Comment: Know it's my actual iPhone